# Exception with WshShell and Show Desktop Link c#

Tags: c#, shell, desktop, shortcut, wsh

i'm having an exception with this code:

```
     public void link()
     {         
         string startupfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + "\\";
         string desktoplink = "c:\windows\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}"
         WshShell shell = new WshShell();
         IWshShortcut shortcut = (IWshShortcut)shell.CreateShortcut(startupfolder);
         shortcut.TargetPath = desktoplink;
         shortcut.Description = "Desktop Autostart";
         shortcut.Save();
     }
```

If i remove the three double-dots (:::) it is working. i assume it is some kind of unaccepted character...

this code is from a kiosk program i'm writing, and all the machines have to start in desktop mode skipping the metro ui.
Can you please help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

as a workout i managed to create a batch file with the shell command and put it in the start folder:

```
    static string startupfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Startup) + "\\";
    static string windowsfolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Windows) + "\\";
    static string nomebat = "Desktop Autostart.bat";
    static string batchcommand = "echo off\nC:\\Windows\\explorer.exe shell:::{3080F90D-D7AD-11D9-BD98-0000947B0257}\nend";
    public void link()
    {        
        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(startupfolder + nomebat))
        {
            Byte[] data = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(batchcommand);
            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

    }
```

i don't know if this could be programmatically a good solution, but it is the only one i found...

any suggestions?